# Como hago que mi codigo ajax llegue al controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, controller

tengo una consulta, quiero enviar estos datos que estoy capturando de un formulario, quiero enviárselos al controller, pero cuando ejecuto  el programa y guarda los datos en las variables y todo, al llegar al ajax este no cae en el breakpoint que puse en el controller, he visto todo y me parece que esta bien y realmente ya no se que hacer, muchas gracias por su tiempo.
Codigo jquery

```
$('#formu').on(' click', '#send', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var nameEmpresa = $("#nameEmpresa").val();
                var precense = $("#precense option:selected").text()
                var category = $("#category").val();
                var local = $("#local").val();
                var pais = $("#pais").val();
                var descripcion = $("#descripcion").val();
                var telefono = $("#telefono").val();
                var sede = $("#sede").val()       
                var contactname = $("#contactname").val();
                var phone = $("#phone").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var cargo = $("#cargo").val();
                var nombreproducto = $("#nombreproducto").val();
                var descripcionproducto = $("#descripcionproducto").val();
                var funcion = $("#funcion").val();
                var usuario = $("#user").val();


               /* var data= $(this).serialize(); //Obtenemos datos*/

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'api/GP_Client/AddClient?clientName=' + nameEmpresa +
                        '&presencia' + precense +
                        '&categoryId=' + category +
                        '&local=' + local +
                        '&pais=' + pais +
                        '&descripcion=' + descripcion +
                        '&telefono=' + telefono +
                        '&sede=' + sede +
                        '&nombreContacto=' + contactname +
                        '&TelefonoContacto=' + phone +
                        '&emailContacto=' + email +
                        '&cargoContacto=' + cargo +
                        '&NombreProducto=' + nombreproducto +
                        '&DescripcionProducto=' + descripcionproducto +
                        '&idFuncionalidad=' + funcion +
                        '&userId=' + usuario,
                    success: function (jsondata, stat) {
                        if (stat == "success") {
                            alert("Se ha agregado un cliente");
                            window.location.reload(false);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert(JSON.parse(jsondata.responseText).Message);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Codigo del controller:

```
   #region <<< AddClient >>>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/GP_Client/AddClient")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddClient(string clientName, string presencia, int categoryId, string local, int pais,
        string descripcion, string telefono, string sede, string nombreContacto, string TelefonoContacto, string emailContacto,
        string cargoContacto, string NombreProducto, string DescripcionProducto, int idFuncionalidad, int userId)
    {
        Models.ClientResponse.AddClientResponse clientResponse = null;

        clientResponse = ApplicationLogic.Client.AddClient(clientName,  presencia,  categoryId,  local,  pais,
         descripcion, telefono,  sede,  nombreContacto,  TelefonoContacto,  emailContacto,
         cargoContacto,  NombreProducto,  DescripcionProducto,  idFuncionalidad, userId);

        return Ok(clientResponse);


    }
    #endregion <<< AddClient >>>
```

Solo quiero enviar todos esos valores al controller pero cuando le doy al boton #send, toma los datos cae en el ajax y se queda pensando y no cae en el controller, he usado este metodo anteriormente y no entiendo porque aqui me esta fallando

Comment: ¿Marca algún error en la consola?

Comment: Tecla F12, pestaña "Network" y revisa lo que sucede; a veces da un error 404 porque la URL está armada de diferente manera, por ejemplo según lo que veo, es probable que tengas algo como `misitioweb.com/Controlador/Vista/api/GP_Client/AddClient?clientName='`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es modificar tu objeto para que quede la siguiente manera:

```
var dataJSON = { 
    'clientName' :  nameEmpresa, 
    'presencia' :  precense,
    'categoryId' :  category,
    'local' :  local,
    'pais' :  pais,
    'descripcion' :  descripcion, 
    'telefono' :  telefono, 
    'sede' :  sede, 
    'nombreContacto' :  contactname, 
    'TelefonoContacto' :  phone, 
    'emailContacto' :  email, 
    'cargoContacto' :  cargo, 
    'NombreProducto' :  nombreproducto, 
    'DescripcionProducto' :  descripcionproducto, 
    'idFuncionalidad' :  funcion, 
    'userId':   usuario }
```

Recuerda que preferiblemente todo lo que envíes por POST debe ir incluido en el cuerpo de la petición y no en el url de la misma.

Recuerda siempre revisar la consola de js para verificar que todos los datos que quieres enviar se serializen correctamente.

Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando los tipos int por su nullable  int?. Al parecer,  el tipo debe de admitir null.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/GP_Client/AddClient")]
public IHttpActionResult AddClient(string clientName, string presencia, int? categoryId, string local, int? pais,
    string descripcion, string telefono, string sede, string nombreContacto, string TelefonoContacto, string emailContacto,
    string cargoContacto, string NombreProducto, string DescripcionProducto, int? idFuncionalidad, int? userId)
{
    Models.ClientResponse.AddClientResponse clientResponse = null;

    clientResponse = ApplicationLogic.Client.AddClient(clientName,  presencia,  categoryId,  local,  pais,
     descripcion, telefono,  sede,  nombreContacto,  TelefonoContacto,  emailContacto,
     cargoContacto,  NombreProducto,  DescripcionProducto,  idFuncionalidad, userId);

    return Ok(clientResponse);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero creamos un objeto en el javascript.

```
  $('#formu').on(' click', '#send', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

             var dataJSON = { 'clientName :' + nameEmpresa +
                    'presencia :' + precense +
                    'categoryId :' + category +
                    'local :' + local +
                    'pais :' + pais +
                    'descripcion :' + descripcion +
                    'telefono :' + telefono +
                    'sede :' + sede +
                    'nombreContacto :' + contactname +
                    'TelefonoContacto :' + phone +
                    'emailContacto :' + email +
                    'cargoContacto :' + cargo +
                    'NombreProducto :' + nombreproducto +
                    'DescripcionProducto :' + descripcionproducto +
                    'idFuncionalidad :' + funcion +
                    'userId: ' + usuario }



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'api/GP_Client/AddClient',
                data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (jsondata, stat) {
                    if (stat == "success") {
                        alert("Se ha agregado un cliente");
                        window.location.reload(false);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(JSON.parse(jsondata.responseText).Message);
                    }
                }
            });
```

}

segundo creamos una entidad que recibirás en el controller

```
public class Entidad{
    string clientName {get;set}; 
    string presencia {get;set}; 
    int categoryId {get;set}; 
    string local {get;set}; 
    int pais {get;set};
    string descripcion {get;set}; 
    string telefono {get;set}; 
    string sede {get;set}; 
    string nombreContacto {get;set}; 
    string TelefonoContacto {get;set};
    string emailContacto {get;set};
    string cargoContacto {get;set};
    string NombreProducto {get;set};
    string DescripcionProducto {get;set};
    int idFuncionalidad {get;set};
    int userId {get;set};
}
```

Tercero recibimos el request en el controller

```
 #region <<< AddClient >>>
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/GP_Client/AddClient")]
public IHttpActionResult AddClient(Entidad request)
{
    Models.ClientResponse.AddClientResponse clientResponse = null;

    clientResponse = ApplicationLogic.Client.AddClient(request.clientName,  request.presencia,  request.categoryId,  request.local,  request.pais,
     request.descripcion, request.telefono,  request.sede,  request.nombreContacto,  request.TelefonoContacto,  request.emailContacto,
     request.cargoContacto,  request.NombreProducto,  request.DescripcionProducto,  request.idFuncionalidad, request.userId);

    return Ok(clientResponse);


}
#endregion <<< AddClient >>>
```

Espero que te ayude.

saludos.

Answer (score -1):

te aconsejaria que armes un array con todos los datos obtenidos y luego lo envies a la API para que no se te haga tan pesado el envio pruebalo porque creo que el problema esta en el envío de los datos.

Comment: Te invito a que pases y leas en el centro de ayuda a [answer]

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]